# Thank you email for promotion

Tags: professionalism, promotion

I am being promoted to a new position and will report to a new manager. My manager sent me the promotion email and copy my new manager. I would like to reply him with a thank you email and I am not sure if I should reply all or just reply to him

Comment: "and I am not sure if I should reply all or just reply to him"  Do you want everyone to see the thank you note or just your new manager?

Comment: Personally, I would go with an individual thank you to your previous manager, and one to your new one.   I avoid Reply All.

Comment: Jennifer, agreed but in this example someone has "already done" an "all" to two important people (the two managers).  IMO it's good to reply all simply to (BRIEFLY) indicate to them both clearly that the message is received and understood.

Comment: Also, it's odd that your manager notified you of your promotion through an email.  Is this a normal practice at your company?

Comment: @sf02 He told me in person then sent me a congratulation email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *VERY* short email would be appropriate.  "Thank you for this new opportunity." is all that needs to be said.

Let me let you in on a secret:  Once you've been up the ladder a ways, you don't always see promoting someone as doing them a favor.  Promotions are usually a sugar-coating for "more responsibility and, if necessary, culpability."  I've seen too many buckle under their new workloads to see promoting someone as a sort of "gift."

Comment: I went with a similar approach but a little longer like "Thank you for the production. I look forward to the new role"

Answer (score 0):

In a job when you get promoted it isn't done as a favour to you. It will be as @Wesley Long mentioned, added responsibility, etc. But it's also something you were given most probably due to:

1. Your (displayed) capability of carrying out a larger role in the organisation
2. The organisation's requirement to fulfil a vacancy. This could be either due to someone moving out of that position or due to the growth of the organisation/department or growth of your current job function.

In the end, if I was writing a thank you note, I would be thanking them (in a single line) for the opportunity given. And yes "reply all" wouldn't be a bad choice since as I understand it's just your former manager and your new manager (as long as it's not the whole department).

Answer (score -1):

Reply to all.  Keep it **VERY BRIEF**.

> Steve, thank you, see you Monday.

In the example given, someone has done an "all" to two important people - the two managers.

It's good to reply-all with a **BRIEF, SHORT, COMPACT** sentence to indicate that **the message is received and understood**.

Nobody cares about or has any interest in thank-yous, congratulations, etc.

Keep it nominal and clear.

The only reason to reply is to indicate "message received and understood".